# Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. typescript const part: number[]

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
function sostavChisla(arr: number[], n:number) {
    const sortedArr:number[] = arr.sort();
    const results:number[] = [];
    const part:number[] = [] ;
  
    for(let i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
      part.push(sortedArr[i]);
  
      const summ:number = part.reduce((acc, x) => acc + x);
      
      if (summ === n) {
        results.push([...part]);
      }
  
      if (summ > n) {
        part.pop();
  
        i = sortedArr.indexOf(part[part.length - 1]);
        
        part.pop();
      }
    }
  
    return results;
  }
```

in result push; Argument of type 'number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. typescript const part: number[]

Comment: The push method can accept any number of arguments, but giving it an array will result in adding an array to the array... You wanted to do `results.push(...part)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust the `push` to:

```
results.push(...part);
```

The `Array.push` method has a *rest paramater* that does show up in auto-completion with a type of `number[]`, but what it means is you can use...

```
push(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Rather than:

```
push([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

In other words, it can accept an unspecified number of arguments, rather than an array of values.

Comment: but output will be [
  1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4,
  1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5,
  8
] and i need [ [ 1, 2, 5 ], [ 1, 3, 4 ], [ 1, 7 ], [ 2, 6 ], [ 3, 5 ], [ 8 ] ]

Comment: @Rashid Then use `number[][]` as the type for `results` instead of `number[]`???

Answer (score 0):

This will merge two arrays into one.

```
results:number[] = [];    
results.push(...part)
```

[MDN Docs - Merge Two Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#merging_two_arrays)

---

What you need is, a multidimensional array type.

```
results:number[][] = []
results.push(part)
```

[Tutorials Point - Declaring a Two-Dimensional array](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm)